# Vue.js ascending or descending Pagination with Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am using the "element-ui" table with vuejs, pagination, listing everything is ok, but it does it while Sort Process, but it cannot sort asc or desc because of my laravel query.
laravel query can hold the query parameter, how to write it in laravel for your help in advance.

Please keep in mind that I am new to laravel when replying

query parametrs
`page: 1 sort: email|asc`

```
http://localhost:3000/user?page=1&sort=name%7Cdesc
http://localhost:3000/user?page=1&sort=email%7Casc
```

```
public function getUser(Request $request)
    {

        $users = User::paginate(10);
        return response()->json($users);
    }
```

```
{
    "current_page": 1,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "serdar",
            "email": "serdar@gmail.com",
            "email_verified_at": null,
            "created_at": "2022-01-03T10:11:46.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-01-03T10:11:46.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Nettie Muller",
            "email": "wilderman.filiberto@example.net",
            "email_verified_at": "2022-01-05T09:34:01.000000Z",
            "created_at": "2022-01-05T09:34:02.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-01-05T09:34:02.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Bridgette Blanda",
            "email": "melba41@example.net",
            "email_verified_at": "2022-01-05T09:34:01.000000Z",
            "created_at": "2022-01-05T09:34:02.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-01-05T09:34:02.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Braden Marvin",
            "email": "van.kerluke@example.com",
            "email_verified_at": "2022-01-05T09:34:01.000000Z",
            "created_at": "2022-01-05T09:34:02.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-01-05T09:34:02.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Donna Gutmann",
            "email": "homenick.rene@example.net",
            "email_verified_at": "2022-01-05T09:34:01.000000Z",
            "created_at": "2022-01-05T09:34:02.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-01-05T09:34:02.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "Ms. Viola Ullrich PhD",
            "email": "okeefe.loma@example.net",
            "email_verified_at": "2022-01-05T09:34:01.000000Z",
            "created_at": "2022-01-05T09:34:02.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-01-05T09:34:02.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "name": "Christy Lakin",
            "email": "turcotte.asha@example.com",
            "email_verified_at": "2022-01-05T09:34:01.000000Z",
            "created_at": "2022-01-05T09:34:02.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-01-05T09:34:02.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "name": "Creola Sporer",
            "email": "smcdermott@example.org",
            "email_verified_at": "2022-01-05T09:34:01.000000Z",
            "created_at": "2022-01-05T09:34:02.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-01-05T09:34:02.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 9,
            "name": "Ms. Kyra Glover MD",
            "email": "margot.labadie@example.org",
            "email_verified_at": "2022-01-05T09:34:01.000000Z",
            "created_at": "2022-01-05T09:34:02.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-01-05T09:34:02.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 10,
            "name": "Catherine Denesik MD",
            "email": "malachi.deckow@example.net",
            "email_verified_at": "2022-01-05T09:34:01.000000Z",
            "created_at": "2022-01-05T09:34:02.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-01-05T09:34:02.000000Z"
        }
    ],
    "first_page_url": "http://kelebek.localhost/kasalar?page=1",
    "from": 1,
    "last_page": 11,
    "last_page_url": "http://kelebek.localhost/kasalar?page=11",
    "links": [
        {
            "url": null,
            "label": "&laquo; Previous",
            "active": false
        },
        {
            "url": "http://kelebek.localhost/kasalar?page=1",
            "label": "1",
            "active": true
        },
        {
            "url": "http://kelebek.localhost/kasalar?page=2",
            "label": "2",
            "active": false
        },
        {
            "url": "http://kelebek.localhost/kasalar?page=3",
            "label": "3",
            "active": false
        },
        {
            "url": "http://kelebek.localhost/kasalar?page=4",
            "label": "4",
            "active": false
        },
        {
            "url": "http://kelebek.localhost/kasalar?page=5",
            "label": "5",
            "active": false
        },
        {
            "url": "http://kelebek.localhost/kasalar?page=6",
            "label": "6",
            "active": false
        },
        {
            "url": "http://kelebek.localhost/kasalar?page=7",
            "label": "7",
            "active": false
        },
        {
            "url": "http://kelebek.localhost/kasalar?page=8",
            "label": "8",
            "active": false
        },
        {
            "url": "http://kelebek.localhost/kasalar?page=9",
            "label": "9",
            "active": false
        },
        {
            "url": "http://kelebek.localhost/kasalar?page=10",
            "label": "10",
            "active": false
        },
        {
            "url": "http://kelebek.localhost/kasalar?page=11",
            "label": "11",
            "active": false
        },
        {
            "url": "http://kelebek.localhost/kasalar?page=2",
            "label": "Next &raquo;",
            "active": false
        }
    ],
    "next_page_url": "http://kelebek.localhost/kasalar?page=2",
    "path": "http://kelebek.localhost/kasalar",
    "per_page": 10,
    "prev_page_url": null,
    "to": 10,
    "total": 101
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**try** 
$users = User::orderBy('name', 'DESC')->paginate(10);

Comment: sort is variable. i just don't want name

Comment: what does it mean **sort is a variable**